# Symfony 2.5 doctrine getRepository() velocity

Tags: php, symfony

I have a entity with a child , the child have a 618 rows.In the Edit view I use children to fill a calendar. When i try to execute the edit Action Symfony throw the error Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.I solve the problem adding `set_time_limit(0)` but why this data extractor slowing the execution ? There any way to speed up this process?Excuse my English is horrible.

```
public function editAction($id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        set_time_limit(0);
        $entity = $em->getRepository('gemaBundle:Activo')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Activo entity.');
        }


        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('gemaBundle:Activo:edit.html.twig', array(
                    'entity' => $entity,
                    'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
                    'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

```js
 function UpdateCalendar()
        {
            {% if entity!=null %}
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                weekends: false,
                theme: false,
                lang: 'es',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events: [{% for estOp in entity.estOps %}
                    {

                        start: '{{estOp.desde | date ('Y-m-d')}}T{{estOp.desde | date ('H:i:s')}}',
                        end: '{{estOp.hasta | date ('Y-m-d')}}T{{estOp.hasta | date ('H:i:s')}}'
                    }
                    {% if not loop.last %},{%  endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                ]
            });

         {%  endif %}
        }
```

Comment: if you don't do any join in your database queries, you will have 618 requests to your database, it could be that

Comment: no, it's a simple one-to- many relation